# Executes js code after redirect to another url

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a page as below, when user clicks the Go href, it will redirect to another page. I want to do some JS manipulations on the redirected page after the page is fully loaded, but have trouble in doing this.

I tried to achieve  this by putting all JS manipulations statements to a setTimeout function, but it seems the statements will not be executed after the redirected page is loaded. In below example, alert('in settimeout') was not executed.

Can you tell me how to achieve this? Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="foo()">Go</a>

<script>
function foo(){
  setTimeout(function (){
    alert('in settimeout'); // **this will not be executed.**
    //js manipulations here ... 
  }, 5000);
  window.location.replace('http://onlineapp.ws');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run JavaScript after you've destroyed the environment it runs in. Leaving a page will destroy that environment.

The only ways to do this would be to:

- load the new page in a frame (and the new page would have to be on [the same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)) and then access it using the [frames API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames).
- pass some information to the server hosting the new page (e.g. via the query string) and read that to determine if the JS should run or not

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Then it is impossible to do this when redirecting to another domain?

Comment: Correct. Unless serious efforts are made by the other domain to allow it, JavaScript on one site cannot alter another site for their visitors. That would be a horrible security problem.

Comment: @Quentin So if I had some html/javascript on my local machine and I want to fill out a text input  inside a form and once I submit the form use that text info to click a button on the page I am redirected to....the only way I could do that is if I add some sort of unique hashed identifier to the redirect url?

Comment: @MikeSandstrom — No, because the JS wouldn't run on the page with the unique hashed identifier. If you are working locally, write a browser extension.

Comment: Great thank you for putting me on to browser extensions they seem to be very useful. Is it possible to write a browser extension that copy’s information from one page and fills out a form on another page with that info?

Comment: @Quentin can you show sample code for the first option?