# How can I redirect to multiple fake websites to fill user's history?

Tags: javascript, .net

I have to do something similar to how this works when you press the "quick exit" button https://www.nationaldahelpline.org.uk/

Basically, when you press that button a new tab with Google will open and the initial website will be redirected through a bunch of fake websites so it goes down in user's history.

I solved opening a new tab by using `window.open`. Then I tried to do some fake redirects with `window.location.replace` in a loop but after the first redirect it's a whole new page so my code is lost...

The backend is in .NET, but I'm not sure if this should be done from frontend or from backend, or a combination of both.

I really don't know how I could achieve this...any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the base site that's redirecting, it's the webserver itself that's listening to http://beta-host.co.uk **(clicking that link will redirect you many times, spamming your browser history)**.

When calling said site, it redirects itself to 312tpfk.beta-host.co.uk and that site redirects to 313tpfk.beta-host.co.uk and that one to 314tpfk.beta-host.co.uk and so on. Each time counting the number up by 1 (312, 313, 314, 315).

The trick here is that it changes only the subdomain, which creates a new browser entry each time.

So, if you want to do that yourself create a redirect on your server that redirects to some up-counting subdomain to create a new browser history entry every time or redirect to that site.

You cannot run javascript in a new page after you destroyed your current one ([credits to Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694949/executes-js-code-after-redirect-to-another-url))

Comment: Ohh, I see now. I thought maybe it's something server related. Wait, it means that I can also redirect to http://beta-host.co.uk/ with `window.location.replace`, and indeed it's working in the same way, but I don't know if it's legally allowed I would say.

Comment: @Kerox I cannot give any advice about the legals, but you may try contacting its webmaster or look up who owns that domain. If you're working on this in a company, it may also be good to ask your company about redirecting to non-company sites.